# Adding tags to cache entry takes a long time using PhpFastCache with Memcached driver

Tags: php, caching, memcached, phpfastcache

Here is the code:

```
    public static function applyInvalidationTags(ExtendedCacheItemInterface $cacheItem, $values): void
    {
        $isSomething = false;
        $tags = [];
        foreach ($values[0] as $value) {
            $tags[] = 'product_id_' . $value->id;

            if (!$isSomething && $value->isSomething) {
                $tags[] = 'isSomething';
                $isSomething = true;
            }
        }

        $cacheItem->addTags($tags);
    }
```

When I remove this line : '$cacheItem->addTags($tags);' my request takes about 1.6s instead of 2.6s. There is always less than 19 objects in $values[0]. Meaning there can be 20 tags maximum on a cache entry.

I need those tags to be able to invalidate the cache when needed. Without that I would have to reduce the caching time drastically, from 2h to minutes.

Any idea why putting tags takes so much time and how I would be able to improve this?

For information, I have good performance when the cache is hit. I'm using Memcached driver, but I tried using Redis instead and I do not have this issue when using it. Sadly my lead does not want to use Redis and insists on using Memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having investigated, the issue was that I had too many cache entries with the same 'search' tag (like ten of thousands entries).

PhpfastCache does tagging by creating a cache entry for each tags. Then when adding a tag on a cache entry, it first retrieves it, then modify it and resend it to Memcached. So there was also a memory issue.

Anyway I do recommend using Redis instead of Memcached as I had less performance issues during testing. Besides Redis is a much more complete caching solution.

Answer (score 0):

How many products do you have in your cache exactly ?
Tags are meant to be used "oneToMany" way, not "manyToOne" way, which could explains why you're facing performances issues.

Also, if you are using "disk-based" driver it'll be far less effective than memory-based drivers like Redis (and others) due to the I/O activity that can kill the performances of your app.

Comment: I have this issue even if I flush the cache. And it tries adding 18 product, which means I have 21. Tags being 18 product ids, 'isSomething', 'search' and 'query'.

I'm using a memory based driver (memcached). However you are right about using redis as a driver as I do not have this issue. I tried pushing for implementing a redis cache solution instead but my lead doesn't want to, he thinks it is harder to install and configure. I disagree with his assesment but I did not get him to install redis. I'm updating this issue with the information I put there.

Comment: In this case this is probably a low-performance backend issue, tags are a little CPU-greedy but nothing extraordinary.